# VS 2013 - DLL unloaded while debugging in a specific order

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, iis-express

My issue is related to debugging projects in VS 2013.

I have two projects that need to run together. One of them is an MVC Web API project and the other is a WPF application that needs the web API. While debugging if I "start new instance" of the Web API project first and then the WPF application, I can see in the output window that almost all of the DLLs that were initially loaded as part of the Web API instance get unloaded. As a result, I get the "Could not load assembly..." error when I connect to the web API through the WPF application. I am referencing a specific version of the DLL which gets unloaded and there is an older version of the DLL in the GAC which gets "loaded" (I can see it getting replaced in the bin folder of the API project). If I run the projects in reverse order that is WPF first and API second, it works fine.

So just curious, is there any setting to prevent the DLL unloading?